# complexity analysis - is my analysis correct?

Tags: python, time-complexity

I just did a complexity analysis, I would love to hear some feedback if my thought process is ok:

I learn phyton by the way

the code:

```
def f(L):
     n = len(L)
     while n > 0:
         n = n // 2
         for i in range(n):
             if i in L:
                 L.append(i)
     return L
```

my analysis:

- the while loop is an O(log n) complexity ( easy to see, since its n/2 then n/2^-2..... n/2^-n
- the inner part is the more complex part for me
  the loop itself is actually the sum of geometric series, where the first element is n,with q= 1/2, and N = log n
  $$ S_{n:}=n\cdot \sum _{i=1}^{log:n}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^i=\frac{n\left(\left(2^{-1}\right)^{log:n}-1\right)}{\frac{1}{2}-1}=\frac{1}{-\frac{1}{2}}+\frac{n}{\frac{1}{2}}=n $$
  [image of the equation, since latex seem to do problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1H2Ui.png)

and the append is another function with O(n)

so combining everything it should be O(n^2 log n )
the solution that appear in my book say it should be O(n^2), but there is no further explanation
I guess that there is something wrong with my inner loop analysis.

thanks to all

Comment: You may not say "the while loop is an O(log n) complexity".

Comment: Append to a `list` in Python is O(1), amortized atleast. But `if i in L` is O(n) though

Comment: The very first iteration will add to the list the numbers `1,2,..., n/2`. Since next you only decrease `n`, all the time `if i in L` condition will be true, thus you will add totally `n/2 + n/4 + n/8 ... + 1` elements, which totals to `n` elements indeed. So in terms of adding new elements, you could equivalently replace the whole `while` loop with `for i in range(n): L.append(i)`, having O(n) complexity. But since you also have to check `if i in L` every time before adding an element (and every time it's true), you get O(n*n)

Comment: The language is called Python, not "phyton".

Answer (score -1):

I disagree with @Yves Daoust's analysis of time complexity for the following reasons:

1. Looking at your code, you define the initial state of n based on len(L).  So the Maximum runtime of the while loop is n//2 which implies O(n) complexity.
2. The run time of the if loop is (n/2) which again implies an O(n) complexity

Therefore the Overall runtime is O(n^2) 'worst-case' which is what the Big O analysis is intended to define.

Comment: In what way do you disagree with my answer ? We both say O(n²). (Though it is quite wrong that "the runtime of the while loop is n//2".)

Comment: Sorry about that, I missed your conclusion.  I guess we both arrive at the same result using slightly different logic.

Comment: By the way, you missed that as `L` lengthens, `i in L` lengthens as well.